# Getting the old html after an click event in selenium handler java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-hub

I have created a custom handler in interactive selenium as below

```
public class SomeHandler implements InteractiveSeleniumHandler {
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());
  public String processDriver(WebDriver driver) {
    String accumulatedData = "";
    try {
      Configuration conf = NutchConfiguration.create();
      new WebDriverWait(driver, conf.getLong("libselenium.page.load.delay", 3));
      WebElement more = driver.findElement(By.className("ulBlueLinks"));
      more.click();
      LOG.error("before collecting data:");
      JavascriptExecutor jsx = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
      jsx.executeScript("document.body.innerHTML=document.body.innerHTML;");
  accumulatedData =  driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getAttribute("innerHTML");      
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
      LOG.error(StringUtils.stringifyException(e));
    }
    return accumulatedData;
  }
  public boolean shouldProcessURL(String URL) {
  return true;
  }
}
```

The issue is some times I get the whole data (the data including after click event) and some time it is not getting the dynamic data.

Note: I am able to see the click event in the browser. I am using the below:

1. Firefox 61
2. Selenium 3.13
3. Apache Nutch 1.14

Comment: add return "jsx.executeScript(" return document.body.innerHTML=document.body.innerHTML;");"

Answer (score 1):

After click wait for sometime to get the page loaded.

you could wait for `document.readyState = complete` which will wait till the page gets loaded.

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
```

Comment: I have tried but it's not working. Also the page is not get loaded completely. Some part of the page is getting loaded. So I think it's not working

Comment: then you can find the last element getting loading and keep an explicit wait on that element like expected_condition.is_element_visible something like that. that would wait till the page gets loaded.

Comment: more info on explicit waits here http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: can you provide some example?

Comment: try `element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))` change the locator